# When using WordPress how do you tell how many read a post when the post is also shown on often visited home page?

Tags: blog, tracking, homepage

I've recently published my first post with Wordpress, however figured out that the blog posts will all be read on the home page - as I'm presuming you can't write different posts on different 'menu' options on the site.

When seeing how many viewers I have - my home page is a lot higher than my blog post viewers, which can't make sense as everyone that went on read my blog post. How am I meant to tell the difference on viewers per post, once I'm writing posts frequently?

Comment: Since this came from WP site I assume you are using WP. You can have different posts under different menu items.  You add a category to the post and then have the menu item display posts in that category.  This doesn't answer your question though and I doubt anyone will have a definitive answer.

Comment: You shouldn't show your posts on the home page in their entirety.  I recommend just showing a snippet on your home page, then users will have to click to the permalink page to read the whole thing.   It makes it much easier to track.  Use the "more" tag in each post: https://en.support.wordpress.com/more-tag/